# C# How to get variable to a different form

Tags: c#, winforms, get

I have two windows forms. One of them has a variable.
In that form, I have created a get method:

```
public string getUSERID
{
    get
    {
        return userID;
    }
}
```

In the second form, I am attempting to use this method like so:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserID = Form1.getUSERID();
}
```

For reasons I do not understand, the second form does not recognize getUSERID as a viable method for Form1, and I have no idea why.
I've searched the forums, and the answer I keep finding is exactly what I did: build a "get/set" method, and activate it with FormX.get/set.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: To calrify - Form 1 is the first form that opens. While it's open, I am opening Form 2 from within form 1 like so:

```
Form Form2 = new Form2();
                            Form2.Show();
                            conn.Close();
                            Hide();
```

(The connection is because form 1 used a connection until now).
Now, since I'm opening Form2 before I hide Form1, I thought that the data in Form1 would still be available during FormLoad of Form2, so I can extract the variable from it, then close Form1.

Comment: Think about this: is `Form1` initialized? `Form1` is a class name, you have to instantiate it like `Form1 frm= new Form1();`. After that, you may access `frm.getUSERID`

Comment: You are trying to access an instance property through the class.

Comment: Anyway, I think you've got another bigger problem. Trying to read a property of `Form1` in the `Load` event of `Form2` denotes a design fault. Maybe you should edit your question and telling us what are you trying to do, e.g. passing a form property to another form being both created by a third form

Comment: You are attempting to access Form1 in the same way you would access a static class with a static property. Since it is a form you would need to instantiate an instance of the `Form1` class before accessing the getter method.

Comment: I've edited to explain what I'm trying to do.
Thanx guys! :)

Comment: See if my answer fits your requirements

Comment: As a tangential piece of advice, naming a variable `Form2` when you already have a class named `Form2` is going to needlessly confuse things.  Better style is to start local variables with a lowercase letter (e.g. `Form form2 = new Form2();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your clarification, what would i do is this. In Form2 create a parameter constructor,like this:

```
string form1UserId="";
public Form2(string UserID)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.form1UserId=UserID;
}
```

And then, from Form1 you just have to do this:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(userID);
frm2.Show();
conn.Close();
Hide();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does, but Form is a builtin Visual Studio class. How do I change it so that it has a constructor that contains a variable?

Comment: @NimrodYanai Your Form2 `Inherites` from `Form`. So you can override its methods for example. But is not the same, Form2 is your class, and you can add constructors to it

Comment: i.e. when I try to do what you wrote, it gives me an error message that Form does not contain a constructor that receives a variable.

Comment: Ah I see what I did wrong...
Checking to see if this solved the issue.

Comment: @NimrodYanai see my edited answer. The problem may be because you was creating a Form instance,instead of a Form2 one

Comment: Perfection!
And with this solution, I don't even need the get/set property from window 1 :)

Just to be sure though, I can still also use an empty constructor if I want to come to Form2 from other forms right?

Comment: And yes that was indeed the problem :)

Comment: Right,you can add all the constructor you want, is the parameters recieved are different. Parameterless constructor is the default, in fact you already got one when you add a form, calling `InitializeComponent()'

Comment: Remember to call the no-arg constructor from the 1-arg version to make sure `InitializeComponent()` gets called.  Or just call `InitializeComponent()` directly from the 1-arg constructor.

Comment: In fact, in your new constructor you should add that call,i forgot to add it, i'll do it now

Comment: You are right @adv12, i've edited answer to reflect that

Comment: Yeah I did that. I'm not THAT much of a noob ;)

Thanx, this solved my issue perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Two things are wrong here.  First is that you define `getUSERID` as a property but are trying to access it like a method.  Second is that you define `getUSERID` as a non-static method but are trying to use it as a static method.  To fix the first problem, rename `getUSERID` to `USERID` in your property declaration and access it without the parentheses (i.e. `someForm.USERID`).  To fix the second problem, you'll need to access the `USERID` property from an *instance* of `Form1`, not as a static member on the class `Form1`, like so:

**Form2.cs**

```
private Form1 _f1;
public Form2(Form1 f1): Form2()
{
    _f1 = f1;
}
// ...
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserID = _f1.USERID;
}
```

Comment: As I commented in OP question,this seems a bit nonsense, as newForm.getUSERID likely would be empty, unless it is initialized in Form1 constructor.

Comment: @Pikoh, yeah, I considered putting a comment between the two lines saying something like "show the form, etc." to indicate that I wasn't showing the full code necessary to make the usage meaningful.  I suppose I'll do that now.

Comment: The problem is that Form1 is the first firm and is already open, and the variable in question is filled from an SQL database a few lines before I open Form2. Therefor, opening an instance of Form1 from Form2 won't help me, because Form1 is not automatically connected to the database.

To be clear - Form1 is a small window that checks user name and password with the database, then fills the variable of "userID" that belong to said user, then opens Form2, which should take the userID, then Form1 should close, leaving only form2.

Comment: Right.  So you need to add a constructor to `Form2` that accepts as a parameter the existing instance of `Form1` and stores it in a private field.  Then you can access that private field from your `Form2_Load`.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined it as a property, not a method, so no () is needed.

Also, to access it without creating an instance (`new Form1()`), it would have to be static.

Answer (score 0):

> the second form does not recognize getUSERID as a viable method

That's because it isn't a method, it's a property. Omit the parens, and you'll find it works.

Comment: That doesn't work either :\
Now it has the red line under ALL of the statement, not just the property name.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your case `getUSERID` is a read only property of string type, which will return the `userID` of that class. And one more thing to be noticed is that the property is not defined as static so an object reference is required to access the property value; so the signature of the page load will be

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 newForm1= new Form1();
    UserID = newForm1.getUSERID; // UserID will be same as that of Form1's userID
}
```

You can define the property as static inn-order to avoid creating instance. if so you can access the same property from any other forms without creating instance of the form1. So the definition of the Class `Form1` will be like the following

```
public class Form1
{
    private static string _UserId = "Some value";

    public static string UserId
    {
        get { return _UserId; }
    }
    // rest of statements
}
```

So that you can access the  `UserId` from any other forms by using `Form1.UserId` no need to create an instance of the  `Form1`

Comment: I can't use a static variable, as Form1 gets that variable from a database and it changes depending on who the user is (identified by username and password).

Answer (score 0):

Just give the second form the variable when you open it, like so:

```
 SecondForm f2 = new SecondForm(YourVariable);
   f2.Show();


   //Global Variable
   var SaveVariableFromForm1;

   protected override void OnCreate(var YourVariable)
    {
      //Imagine this is the Form2 OnCreate();
      SaveVariableFromForm1 = YourVariable;
    }
```

And catch the variable on the 2º Form's OnCreate Method save it in a Global Variable and use it were ever you feel like it, hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. Can you please give an example? I've never seen a Form open with a variable provided on open like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public **static** string getUSERID  
  {
     get
      {
        return userID;
      }
   }

   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        UserID = Form1.getUSERID(); // If the property has static it's possible to write like this.
   }



   (or)



  public string getUSERID
   {
     get
      {
        return userID;
      }
   }

   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        Form1 f= new Form1();
        UserID = f.getUSERID();
   }
```

Comment: When I try to make the property static, it refuses to return the variable, giving the following error message:
"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Form1.UserID'"